# Possible to filter out results this way in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am using Elastic Search on AWS, with C# and NEST, and wanted to ask for some help to addressing my problem. Consider some documents in the format below.

**GroupId** - a "chat room" that holds lots of threads

**ThreadId** - a specific thread where messages took place

**Subject** - the subject of a particular thread (does not change for each thread)

**Message** the chat the person wrote to the thread

So an example would be this (the first 3 documents are part of the same thread, the fourth document is a new thread). All belong to the same group.

```
{
 Id: 4bd0a786-488b-4e97-a7cf-eb5cc223975e,
 GroupId: 6bd0a123-4bb3-4c91-abcf-cb5cc114314c,
 ThreadId: 22d1b2ac-4ed3-5c91-d2fa-cb2ba44cba4d,
 DateCreated: "2018-11-1 01:00:00",
 Subject: "iPhone",
 Message: "Are you going to buy the new iPhone?"
}

{
 Id: bcd0a1d3-1b1e-5f1c-a7cf-ebdce22eeb5c,
 GroupId: 6bd0a123-4bb3-4c91-abcf-cb5cc114314c,
 ThreadId: 22d1b2ac-4ed3-5c91-d2fa-cb2ba44cba4d,
 DateCreated: "2018-11-2 01:00:00",
 Subject: "iPhone",
 Message: "No, you?"
}

{
 Id: bcd04e86-518b-4c16-c6cf-eb444c3b175d,
 GroupId: 6bd0a123-4bb3-4c91-abcf-cb5cc114314c,
 ThreadId: 22d1b2cc-4ed3-5c91-d2fa-cb2ba44cba4d,
 Subject: "iPhone",
 DateCreated: "2018-11-3 01:00:00",
 Message: "I did it and I like it!"
}
```

## A different thread and message

```
{
 Id: cbd04786-418b-3c16-b6cf-eb4cc333975e,
 GroupId: 6bd0a123-4bb3-4c91-abcf-cb5cc114314c,
 ThreadId: 11d0a3cb-4dd3-4c91-defa-cb2ca113314c,
 Subject: "Party tomorrow?",
 DateCreated: "2018-11-8 11:05:00",
 Message: "Are you going to come to the party? Bring your iPhone or camera so we can take some pictures!"
}
```

## My Query

The goal is to find all documents whose subject or message contain 'term' in it for a given groupId. I've gotten this far, and get back all documents, but now I want to make it more robust.

```
     var results = client.Search<IndexedMessage>(s => s.Type("indexedmessage")
                    .Query(q => 
                           (q.Match(m => m.Field(f => f.Body).Query(term)) || 
q.Match(m => m.Field(f => f.Subject).Query(term)))
                           && q.Match(m => m.Field(f => f.GroupId).Query(groupId.ToString()))
                    )
                    );
```

So this works for the most part, however now the issue is this if I search for 'iPhone' I get all documents because the subject and message contain 'iPhone'

In a case like this, what I was hoping to do is make it so if the user searches 'iPhone':

- If the message contains 'iPhone', then it is always returned
- If the subject contains iPhone, but not the message, then return it, but if more than one subject contains iPhone (and message does not), then only take the most recent document. This is because if 1,000 messages are written on a 'iPhone' thread, then the query will return 1,000 messages.

So that means while document #1 and #2 and #3 both contain iPhone in the subject, I'd only want to return Document # 1 (because message contains iPhone) and document # 3 (because it's more recently created than # 2)

Is something like this possible in Elastic Search using aggregations or anything of that sort?

I was going to just do this in C# after I get the duplicates but I feel like that won't be performant, what do you think?

Thank you so much for your consideration!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making another query (inside the same method) and just doing this:

```
        var subjectResults = client.Search<IndexedMessage>(s => s.Type("indexedmessage")
        .Query(q =>
               q.Match(m => m.Field(f => f.Subject).Query(term)) && q.Match(m => m.Field(f => f.GroupId).Query(groupId.ToString()))
              ).Sort(sort => sort
                     .Descending(f => f.DateCreated)).Size(1)
        );
```

Then I concatenated them together and returned it. Works pretty well!